# Mouse sensitivity while aiming grenades

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

While playing XCOM EU on the pc, I notice that the mouse sensitivity while aiming grenades is quite high,  high enough to make careful aiming difficult,  while the sensitivity is alright at the other times. Aiming grenades with keyboard seems alright.

Is this a bug or a feature?  Is there  any way to adjust the most sensitivity for aiming?

Comment: Pretty sure it is a bug.  Also, it is much easier to aim grenades in Enemy Within, so if you were considering the expansion...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to change the sensitivity, but what always worked for me is using the mouse wheel to scroll to a higher altitude. It doesn't fix it, but it's a little easier, at least for me.